# Update product visibility Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, create-product, visibility

I am creating a product programmatically, trying to set the **visibility** with below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$product->setVisibility(4);

$product->save();
```

The above code works perfectly, but it is not working when I use like below.

```
$product->setVisibility('Catalog, Search');
```

The product is saving, but visibility is not set when used like above. Can anyone suggest me how to update the visibility? I am reading it from the csv file and updating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$product->setVisibility('Catalog, Search');
```

This will not work because In **Visibility** you can set Integer value.

so work around is

```
$array =  [ 1 => 'Not Visible Individually',
            2 => 'Catalog',
            3 => 'Search',
            4 => 'Catalog, Search'
        ];

$currentValue = array_search("Catalog, Search",$array);
$product->setVisibility($currentValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

We have to pass the Integer value for the "Catalog, Search" and it's 4.

When you check in Magento 2 admin. Visibility field have following options:

```
<option data-title="Not Visible Individually" value="1">Not Visible Individually</option>
<option data-title="Catalog" value="2">Catalog</option>
<option data-title="Search" value="3">Search</option>
<option data-title="Catalog, Search" value="4">Catalog, Search</option>
```

So you have to use code like

```
$visibility_array =  ['Not Visible Individually' => 1,
        'Catalog' => 2,
        'Search' => 3,
        'Catalog, Search' => 4
    ];

$visibility = $visibility_array['Catalog, Search'];
$product->setVisibility($visibility);
```